# Make order of 'to-do list' without sort() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I have 'TO-DO LIST' like below.**
And I want to arrange 'TO-DO LIST' following "Argent Level", "The time required" and "Incoming order" **without sort() function**

```
# "Argent Level", "The time required" and "Incoming order"
work_list = [
             "Low_Level, 1, A.Login Error",
             "High_Level, 3, B.User info Error",
             "Nomal_Level, 1, C.Admin Error",
             "Low_Level, 2, D.Icon change of User",
             "High_Level, 3, E.Email export Error",
             "Nomal_Level, 1, F.Photo size Error",
             "High_Level, 2, G.Admin Page Error",
             "Nomal_Level, 3, H.Customer Page Error",
             "Low_Level, 1, I.Image box Error",
             "Nomal_Level, 3, J.Border Error",
             "Low_Level, 1, K.Background Color Error",
             "High_Level, 2, L.SignUp Error",
]
```

For example, There are same "High_Level" List like below.

```
"High_Level, 3, B.User info Error",
"High_Level, 3, E.Email export Error",
"High_Level, 2, G.Admin Page Error",
"High_Level, 2, L.SignUp Error",
```

First I want to make this list like below order by "The time required" and if they have same "The time required", next order by Incoming order using a capital letter of "Incoming order"

```
"High_Level, 2, G.Admin Page Error",
"High_Level, 2, L.SignUp Error",
"High_Level, 3, B.User info Error",
"High_Level, 3, E.Email export Error",
```

---

**And I tried to make code like this. But It was not correct.**

```
high_level_list = []
nomal_level_list = []
low_level_list = []

for i in range(0, len(work_list)):
    if "High_Level" in work_list[i]:
        high_level_list.append(work_list[i])

for i in range(0, len(work_list)):
    if "Nomal_Level" in work_list[i]:
        nomal_level_list.append(work_list[i])

for i in range(0, len(work_list)):
    if "Low_Level" in work_list[i]:
        low_level_list.append(work_list[i])

for i in range(0, len(high_level_list)):
    if high_level_list[i][1] >= 3:
        temp = high_level_list[-1]
        high_level_list[-1] = high_level_list[i]
        high_level_list[i] = temp
        print(high_level_list)
```

---

**I wanna output like below**

```
"High_Level, 2, G.Admin Page Error",
"High_Level, 2, L.SignUp Error",
"High_Level, 3, B.User info Error",
"High_Level, 3, E.Email export Error",

"Nomal_Level, 1, C.Admin Error",
"Nomal_Level, 1, F.Photo size Error",
"Nomal_Level, 3, H.Customer Page Error",
"Nomal_Level, 3, J.Border Error",

"Low_Level, 1, A.Login Error",
"Low_Level, 1, I.Image box Error",
"Low_Level, 1, K.Background Color Error",
"Low_Level, 2, D.Icon change of User",
```

Comment: Is it intentional that those are just strings and not, e.g. tuples?

Comment: Also, why don't you want to use `sorted`? With a properly structured list like `[["Low_Level, 1, A.Login Error"], ["High_Level, 3, B.User info Error"], ...]`, this would be trivial.

Comment: @chepner I want to improve my algorithm background. This is reason why I don't use sorted() function.

Comment: @tobias_k it is not intentional. I tried to change from string to integer. Like this ```["High_Level", 2, "G.Admin Page Error"],["High_Level", 2, "L.SignUp Error"],
["High_Level", 3, "B.User info Error"],
["High_Level", 3, "E.Email export Error"]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will want to convert your `work_list` to a list of tuples, instead of just strings, so you can access the individual fields, in particular the number that you need in the last step.

```
>>> work_list_tuples = [tuple(s.split(", ")) for s in work_list]
```

Your first loops should work, but you can make them more compact as list comprehensions

```
>>> high = [x for x in work_list_tuples if x[0] == "High_Level"]
```

Your last loop is kind of a bugged insertion sort, but instead of trying to fix that you can use another list comprehension to filter the `high` items where the value is 3 or higher, too:

```
>>> high_3 = [x for x in high if int(x[1]) >= 3]
```

This gives you

```
[('High_Level', '3', 'B.User info Error'),
 ('High_Level', '3', 'E.Email export Error')]
```

Do the same for `normal` and `low` level and for `high` with lower than 3, and put the lists back together.

```
>>> high_3 + high_12 + norm + low
[('High_Level', '3', 'B.User info Error'),
 ...
 ('High_Level', '2', 'L.SignUp Error'),
 ...
 ('Nomal_Level', '1', 'C.Admin Error'),
 ...
 ('Low_Level', '1', 'K.Background Color Error')]
```

However, in all remotely practical application, I would strongly suggest just using `sort` (the list method) or `sorted` (the builtin function) with an appropriate key function, e.g. like this:

```
>>> sorted(work_list_tuples, key=lambda x: ("HNL".index(x[0][0]), -int(x[1])))
[('High_Level', '3', 'B.User info Error'),
 ('High_Level', '3', 'E.Email export Error'),
 ('High_Level', '2', 'G.Admin Page Error'),
 ('High_Level', '2', 'L.SignUp Error'),
 ('Nomal_Level', '3', 'H.Customer Page Error'),
 ('Nomal_Level', '3', 'J.Border Error'),
 ('Nomal_Level', '1', 'C.Admin Error'),
 ('Nomal_Level', '1', 'F.Photo size Error'),
 ('Low_Level', '2', 'D.Icon change of User'),
 ('Low_Level', '1', 'A.Login Error'),
 ('Low_Level', '1', 'I.Image box Error'),
 ('Low_Level', '1', 'K.Background Color Error')]
```

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make code without ```sort``` or ```sorted``` function and I thought I could do that. But, when I checked your comment, I realized that it is better way to user sort function or sorted function.

But thank you so much and I tried to do once again based on your comments.